# OSX Mail restored from backup - many folders missing

Tags: macos, backup, restore, osx-mavericks, apple-mail

Friday I messed up the user account on my macbook (10.9 Maverick). I won't bore you with the details. It seemed like the complete library was reset. I use Crashplan for backup, plus Time Machine. The TM backup was 10 days old, the CP backup seems up-to-date. I downloaded the complete Library folder from CP, renamed the original Library folder, moved the restored one into place, and most of my settings are back.

Except for (Apple) Mail... The accounts are there, the inbox is there, and some folders. I use about 30 folders to organize mail, and only 5 are restored. I'm quite sure it is there, but somehow Mail doesn't see it or ignores it.

What can I do to restore Mail to its original state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've installed Mail Exporter Pro: http://mailexporterpro.com/

This tool can convert Apple Mail EMLX files to EML or MBOX or Outlook. With the trial I did a test to see if it works. The trial is limited to 10 mails per folder. It worked, so I bought it. For $47 having my mail (around 50k messages) back and working is worth the price.

From EML I have imported it into Thunderbird using the ImportExportTools addon. I couldn't find this via the Thunderbird addon search function, but Google is your friend:

https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/thunderbird/addon/importexporttools/

I suppose it is possible to import this into Apple Mail as well, but I haven't tried that.

Answer (score 1):

`Mail` stores the mail folders in `~/Library/Mail/V2`. (which is `/Users/USERNAME/Library/Mail/V2/`, not `/Library/Mail/V2/`)
Check your backup and your current installation, if the missing folders are located there.

How is/are your account(s) connected inside Mail (IMAP/POP3/Exchange)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've downloaded and restored `~/Librar/Mail`. If I look in that folder, there are probably hundreds or thousands of subfolders like `archive.mbox/D09484VCDKE/Data/3/5/1/messages` and then several files like `53204.emlx`. In Mail I see only 5 of those mbox folders. The rest is simply missing. Could this be a rights problem? All accounts work via POP3.